# Get number after character from string?

Tags: c

I have this function , that check if the input is like that `d1,d7,d65,` etc - means it starts with a "d" and then has a number .

I would like to check if its the structure , then return the number **after the d**.

Whats the most efficient way to do so ? can it be done using `scanf` only ?

Comment: What kind of efficiency are you looking for? Readability, maintainability, code size, memory, execution time?

Comment: Could you please provide [mcve]?

Comment: Sorry, thanks, the code runs on a tiny micro processor, so less lines of code, and use of memory.

Comment: If the input was `"d 1,d7 , d 65 ,"` (Added spaces here and there), what should be the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sscanf` and check the return value, if it returns 1 then an integer has been read successfully (via `%d`) - and that matches the format you need; otherwise `t` does not have the desired format.

---

```
int read_fmt( char t[], int *n )
{
    return sscanf( t, "d%d", n );
}

int main ()
{
    char t[] = "d8787";
    int n = 0;
    if( read_fmt( t, &n ) == 1 )
    {
        printf( "correct format, n = %d\n", n );
    }
    else
    {
        perror( "incorrect format\n" );
    }
}
```

Comment: excellent. Don't know why people are down voting . I used that without the function with 2 lines, and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Since the structure is trivial some simple checks and strol should do the trick, something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

const char* input = "d1,d7,d65,d171";
bool error = false;
const char* ptr = input;

while (*ptr != '\0')
{
  // not starting with d so break with failure
  if (*ptr != 'd') { error = true; break; }
  // we must find a sequence of "number,..." or "number\0"
  else
  {
    // not any character available, break with failure
    if (++ptr == '\0') { error = true; break; }
    else
    {
        int v = strtol(ptr, &ptr, 10);

        // add error check for strtol

        printf("found: %d\n", v);

        // skip comma
        if (*ptr && *ptr == ',') ++ptr;
    }
  }
}

printf("error = %d\n", error);
```

But you must take care of all various edge cases to ensure proper behavior.

Comment: Using the same pointer for the end with `int v = strtol(ptr, &ptr, 10);` negates the ability to test for _no conversion_.